# How to create a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a cmd file to loop through each .xml file in c:\ folder and echo the datetime stamp of that file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Folder"
for %%A in (*.xml) do echo %%~nA %%~tA
```

Answer (score 0):

@echo off
REM Next command opens Microsoft Word
start /d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Word" WINWOR